# How to display Glassfish data using Java?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I want to create JSF page which displays Glassfish connections. The web page will be hosted on the server. How I can get this information from Glassfish?

Best wishes

Comment: What do you mean by glassfish connections? are you developing a monitoring application?

Comment: No, It's just a simple JSF page. I just need to monitor the performance.

Comment: That's what the admin console is for, any specific reason you can't just use that?

Comment: have you tried [Sun GlassFish Enterprise Manager Performance Monitor 1.0](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-7194/gifpw/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a 3rd party JMX monitoring tool instead of building your own tool to monitor performance?  The Performance Monitor comment above is valid for GlassFish 2.x, but not GlassFish 3.x (Performance Monitor is not available for GlassFish 3.x).  If you are using GlassFish 3.x, read on.

Otherwise, the monitoring data you want is available via the RESTful Monitoring API. Here are some resources you can utilize to help you.

- http://engineeringnotebook.org/building-a-glassfish-monitoring-client-using-rest/
- http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/2010/08/glassfish-administration-the-rest-of-the-story/
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gjipx.html#scrolltoc

Also, the RESTful API will render in HTML, JSON, and XML.  So, you can begin by perusing the monitoring tree by pointing your browser to http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain, and the RESTful monitoring will render in HTML.

Also note that you will have to enable monitoring to get to the data you want.  The admin guide will show you how to enable monitoring.

Hope this helps.